# Get the all document's by year mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Example of one document:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "quarter":{
         "quarter":4,
         "year":2009
      },
      "ticker":"MMM"
   },
   "data":{
      "C1":2.4676424337728315,
      "C10":-1.7952609553649523,
      "C11":-0.024843006011523616,
      "C12":19.3099694596474
   }
}
```

So I want to get all the documents equal to year 2009 by using pymongo.
Thank you

Comment: Is [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oUW14WCnOU-) what are you looking for?

Comment: try `find({"_id.quarter.year" : 2009})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the query to find the years is `find({"_id.quarter.year": 2009})`

```
   import pymongo

   client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://uname:pass@ip:port/") ##update your Atlas DB connection details
   db = client.simple ##Replace <simple> with your atlas db name
   years = db.cars  ##Replace <cars> with the Collection name

   requests = years.find({"_id.quarter.year": 2009})  ##This returns an object

   ##to print out the documents in the requests object
   for doc in requests:
      print(doc)
```